# Interior Wall French Windows

Tags: walls, basement, interior

Does anybody know where I could find, reasonable priced, french windows that I can use in an interior wall for my finished basement? (Toronto area). That means both sides would look the same. No insulation needed and whether or not you could open them is optional.

See attached screenshot to get an idea what I'm looking for.[image]

Thanks for any suggestion!

Matt

Comment: Are used windows acceptable? If yes, try a salvage yard.

Comment: yes, used is definetly accetable - thx for the tipp!